# Configure Jest global tests setup with .ts file

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I am using ts-jest (Jest and TypeScript) and want to configure
some global setup for all test suites (initialize test database).

I found that there is `globalSetup` options in jest configuration:

```
"jest": {
    "globalSetup": "./jest-config.js"
}
```

but only `.js` file can be used for setup. I want to use `.ts` file because all my code
including code for setup in TypeScript.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I found a solution.

My initial project structure was:

```
.
|--src
|  |--service.ts
|--tests
|  |--service.test.ts
|--dist
|--tsconfig.json 
|--package.json
```

Jest configuration in package.json:

```
"jest": {
  "globals": {
    "ts-jest": {
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json"
    }
  },
  "moduleFileExtensions": ["ts","js"],
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$": "./node_modules/ts-jest/preprocessor.js"
  },
  "testMatch": [
    "**/tests/**/*.test.(ts|js)"
  ],
  "testEnvironment": "node"
}
```

With this configuration `ts-jest` perform in memory transpiling of the .ts files.
I have `outDir` option in `compilerOptions` of my `tsconfig.json`, but nothing is written in that outDir and because I cann't use transpiled jest-config.js

**Then I move tests folder in src and change Jest config**.
New structure of the project is:

```
.
|--src
|  |--service.ts
|  |--tests
|     |--service.test.ts
|     |--jest-config.ts
|--dist
|--tsconfig.json 
|--package.json
```

New Jest config is:

```
"jest": {
  "globalSetup": "./dist/tests/jest-config.js",
  "moduleFileExtensions": ["ts", "js", "json"],
  "testMatch": [
    "**/dist/**/*.test.js"
  ],
  "testEnvironment": "node"
}
```

Now I can use jest-config.js for global setup in Jest.

Addition

- Jest setup file (in my example jest-config.js) must export one async function:

  `module.exports = async function() { ... }`
- Before running the tests, you need to compile source .ts files.

Comment: Issue about this problem in ts-jest project: https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest/issues/411

Comment: This effects code coverage reports. Does it impact debugging?

Comment: thank you - native jest+typescript support sucks. this solution turns everything to a .js and then leverages jest. I spend hours trying to troubleshoot ts-jest and babel crap. this solution work! Thank you!

Answer (score 18):

Global setup is performed before a ts environment is made available, so a workaround is to create the environment manually by requiring *ts-node* at the beginning of the file.

In your jest configuration (`package.json` or `jest.config.js`):

```js
"globalSetup": "./globalSetup.ts"
```

Then in `globalSetup.ts`:

```js
require('ts-node/register');

const setup = (): void => {
  // whatever you need to setup globally
};

export default setup;
```

You can read more about *ts-node* on [github](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node).

Comment: Amazing  
My project structure requires me to place those scripts outside src folder, and this trick save me so much headache.
one thing to notice, I had to use this form of path in the jest config - "<rootDir>/path/to/globalSetup.ts"

Comment: Can confirm this just worked for me.

Comment: In Jest 28.1 (and probably some versions before it as well) there is a configuration option called `setupFilesAfterEnv`, claiming it runs after the Jest test environment is set up. Could this be the solution? If not, what works differently than expected? https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#setupfilesafterenv-array

Answer (score 2):

For anyone with TS error with @remeus's answer, the following change will do the trick:

```
require('ts-node').register({
  transpileOnly: true,
});
```

If you're using absolute imports, use this:

```
require('tsconfig-paths').register();
```

Answer (score 1):

@glinda93 answer helped me, but I got an error in globalTeardown file.

The solution was to add `require('tsconfig-paths').register();` in globalSetup file and:

```js
require('ts-node').register({
  transpileOnly: true,
});

require('tsconfig-paths').register();
```

in global teardown file.

for some reason, it worked if the ts-node register is only in the teardown file.

Answer (score 0):

*I didnt use `require('ts-node/register');`, 

but mine is working, though not sure if my procedure below is correct.*

*Im using `React, Vite, Typescript, Jest, Jest with esm (node --experimental-vm-modules)`*

---

jest config `H:\Using\TLightChat\tlightchat-main\jest.config.js`:

```js
/** @type {import('jest').Config} */
const config = {

...

  transform: {
    '^.+\\.(ts|tsx|js|jsx)$': [
      'ts-jest',
      {
        useESM: true, 
      },
    ],

...
  globalSetup: '<rootDir>/config/jest/jest.globalSetup.ts',
...
  extensionsToTreatAsEsm: ['.ts', '.tsx'],
...
```

tsconfig `H:\Using\TLightChat\tlightchat-main\tsconfig.json`:

```json
  "include": [
...
    "config/**/*",
```

`H:\Using\TLightChat\tlightchat-main\config\jest\jest.globalSetup.ts`

```
// import { GlobalConfig } from 'jest';
// import { Config } from 'jest';
// import { Config, GlobalConfig } from '@jest/types';
import { Config } from '@jest/types';

export default async function (globalConfig: Config.GlobalConfig, projectConfig: Config.ProjectConfig) {
  console.log(globalConfig.testPathPattern);
  console.log(projectConfig.cache);

  // globalThis.__MONGOD__ = mongod;
}

// https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#globalsetup-string
```

- *This file includes the types.*

  *Besides You may also want to:*

  ```
  pnpm i @jest/types -D
  ```