# How to use TypeScript in a Custom Test Environment file in Jest?

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs

I need to enable some global variables to be reachable for my test so I am setting up a Custom Environment to be used in the `testEnvironment` option in my `jest.config.json` to achieve that.

For our project we have a TypeScript file that we use for `setupFilesAfterEnv` option and that works just fine, however the `testEnvironment` seems to support only ES5. Is there any way to use TypeScript in such option?

I successfully created a Custom Jest Environment using ES5 syntax, however since we are injecting global variables I need TypeScript to also declare a global namespace see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42304473/4655076.

```js
{
  ///...
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/test/setup.ts'], // This works with ts
  testEnvironment: '<rootDir>/test/customJestEnvironment.ts', // This doesn't work with ts
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might find this helpful: [Configure Jest global tests setup with .ts file (TypeScript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48318230/configure-jest-global-tests-setup-with-ts-file-typescript)

But basically you can only pass in compiled JS files as environments.

You can do what that article suggests. But it didn't work for me out of the box. So I manually compile my env.

i.e.

in package.json

```sh
"test": "tsc --lib es6 --target es6 --skipLibCheck -m commonjs --esModuleInterop true path/to/env.ts && 
jest --config=jest.config.js",
```

And in jest.config.js

```
{
  testEnvironment: '<rootDir>/path/to/env.js', // Note JS extension.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by using [ts-node](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node) and the following command:

`node -r ts-node/register ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js`

This essentially compiles the typescript on-the-fly, so that jest receives the emitted javascript, without the need of actually compiling your typescript sources to js.

You will need to enable `esModuleInterop` TS compiler option for this to work properly.

#### TestEnvironment.ts

```js
import NodeEnvironment from 'jest-environment-node';
import type {Config} from '@jest/types';

class TestEnvironment extends NodeEnvironment {
    
    constructor(config: Config.ProjectConfig) {
        super(config);
        // this.testPath = context.testPath;
        // this.docblockPragmas = context.docblockPragmas;
    }

    public async setup(): Promise<void> {
        await super.setup();

        console.log('SETTING UP...');
        // await someSetupTasks(this.testPath);
        // this.global.someGlobalObject = createGlobalObject();
    
        // // Will trigger if docblock contains @my-custom-pragma my-pragma-value
        // if (this.docblockPragmas['my-custom-pragma'] === 'my-pragma-value') {
        //   // ...
        // }
    }

    public async teardown(): Promise<void> {
        await super.teardown();
        console.log('TEARING DOWN!');
        // this.global.someGlobalObject = destroyGlobalObject();
        // await someTeardownTasks();
        
    }
}

export default TestEnvironment;
```

**This solution however, will break globalSetup** -- if you use `jest-ts`.

Answer (score 0):

As you might know, typescript files are just superset to javascript to provide strong type checking. Jest's engine/runtime however expects your files in CommonJS format javascript files.

You can have a separate `tsconfig.env.json` just for this `env.ts`. Compile this before running jest test and use the compiled `env.js` in your `jest.config.js`.

```
tsc -p tsconfig.env.json && jest
```

Also i have never seen people writing configuration files in TS.

why CommonJS ? because jest is essentially running on top of node. node supports Javascript files in CommonJS format. Node has started supporting es modules as well recently! This is a big thing!

Answer (score -1):

You can create a `global.d.ts` file at the root of your project.

Then you can define global variables as seen below. In my case, it was a NestJS application, but you can define anything.

```
declare global {
  namespace NodeJS {
    interface Global {
      app: INestApplication;
    }
  }
}
```

This is another example for client project where we define window properties like `innerWidth`;

```
declare namespace NodeJS {
    interface Global {
        innerWidth: number;
        dispatchEvent: Function;
    }
}
```

Comment: The need is to be able to set these variables, not just declare types. The question id basically how to have a environment.ts for Jest.

Answer (score -1):

Inside your `.d.ts` definition file:

```
type MyGlobalFunctionType = (name: string) => void
```

Add members to the browser's window context:

```
interface Window {
  myGlobalFunction: MyGlobalFunctionType
}
```

Same for NodeJS:

```
declare module NodeJS {
  interface Global {
    myGlobalFunction: MyGlobalFunctionType
  }
}
```

Now you declare the root variable

```
declare const myGlobalFunction: MyGlobalFunctionType;
```

Then in a regular `.ts` file, but imported as side-effect, you actually implement it:

```
global/* or window */.myGlobalFunction = function (name: string) {
  console.log("Hey !", name);
};
```

And finally use it elsewhere :

```
global/* or window */.myGlobalFunction("Ayush");

myGlobalFunction("Ayush");
```

Comment: Thank you for the hacky solution to achieve function sharing across tests. The question is about how to write an environment using TypeScript. I.e. setupFile but global.