# Why does jest throw an ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION when trying to use a ts file as custom testEnvironment?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jestjs

I'm switching my TypeScript project to a (pnpm) monorepo and have troubles getting tests to run properly. I have a jest.config.js that uses a custom `testEnvironment` that's written in TypeScript as well. However, ever since I moved the specific project into my packages directory for the monorepo restructuring, jest throws an Error and doesn't run any tests:

```
    TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".ts" for C:\workspaces\repos\the-monorepo\packages\testproject\source\testtools\jsdom-environment-global.spec.ts
```

I tried it with @swc/jest as well as with ts-jest, had a look at [How to use TypeScript in a Custom Test Environment file in Jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58163210/how-to-use-typescript-in-a-custom-test-environment-file-in-jest) (which makes me think "why did this ever work?") and, for whatever reason, it worked fine yesterday. I cleaned jest cache and reinstalled all node_modules to no avail. I also found answers related to `"type": "module"` in package.json, but this doesn't apply to my package. It's not an ESM.

Here's how the jest.config.js looks like:

```js
/** @type {import('@jest/types').Config.InitialOptions} */
const config = {
    silent: true,
    testEnvironment: "<rootDir>/source/testtools/jsdom-environment-global.spec.ts",
    roots: [
        "<rootDir>/source"
    ],
    maxWorkers: "50%",
    transform: {
        "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": ["@swc/jest", {
            sourceMaps: "inline",
            module: {
                strict: false,
                strictMode: false
            },

            jsc: {
                target: "es2021",
                parser: {
                    syntax: "typescript",
                    dynamicImport: true
                }
            }
        }]
    },
    transformIgnorePatterns: [
        "node_modules"
    ],
    testMatch: [
        "**/*/*.spec.ts",
        "**/*/*.test.ts",
        "!**/playwright-tests/**",
        "!**/playwright-tests-smoke/**"
    ],
    moduleFileExtensions: ["ts", "js", "node", "json"],
    reporters: [
        "default"
    ],
    globals: {
        self: {},
        navigator: {},
        jasmine: {},
        __UNIT__: true
    },
    coverageDirectory: "test-results",
    collectCoverage: false,
    collectCoverageFrom: [
        "./source/**/*.ts"
    ],
    coveragePathIgnorePatterns: [
        "/\\.spec\\.ts$/i",
        "/.*node_modules.*/",
        "/.*testtools.*/"
    ],
    coverageReporters: [
        "lcov", "cobertura"
    ],
    coverageProvider: "v8",
    resetMocks: true,
    restoreMocks: true,
    resetModules: true,
    setupFilesAfterEnv: [
        "jest-extended/all",
        "<rootDir>/source/testtools/setup.spec.ts"
    ],
    testPathIgnorePatterns: [
        "<rootDir>/source/testtools/",
        "<rootDir>/source/smoke-tests/",
        "<rootDir>/source/performance-tests/",
        "<rooDir>/source/playwright-tests/",
        "<rooDir>/source/playwright-tests-smoke/"
    ],
    moduleNameMapper: {
        "^@test-helpers": "<rootDir>/source/testtools/index.spec.ts",
        "^@test-tools/(.*)": "<rootDir>/source/testtools/$1",
        '^(\\.{1,2}/.*)\\.js$': '$1'
    }
};
module.exports = config;
```

Why is jest not able to parse the `testEnvironment` if it's a TypeScript file?

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue: there seems to be some confusion around the transformer not being applied to ESM files. In my case, the `jsdom-environment-global.spec.ts` imported an ESM module from a different package within my monorepo. This import triggers an exception because jest tries to import it via `require()`, which is caught and then again imported via dynamic imports. This dynamic import then throws the exception that `ts` is an unknown exception. I'm not sure why these files haven't been transformed, but as of [How to use TypeScript in a Custom Test Environment file in Jest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58163210/how-to-use-typescript-in-a-custom-test-environment-file-in-jest) this seems to be normal.

Bottom line: don't import from ESM files within your jest `testEnvironment` module.

Comment: how did you go about detecting which import was causing the issue?

Comment: i ran it in debug mode (that prints a stack trace), then followed the stack trace and added a breakpoint at the location of the error (unfortunately there's tons of imports so i had to use a conditional breakpoint with the import ending with .ts)